# Speed up Javascript uglification in Play 2.3.x build for external Webjar sources

Tags: javascript, playframework, sbt, uglifyjs2, webjars

I'm using Play framework 2.3.6 and Webjars for web lib dependencies.
That is, my build.sbt contains something like "org.webjars" % "angularjs" % "1.2.26".
To uglify my Javascript sources I added pipelineStages := Seq(rjs, uglify, digest, gzip) to my build.sbt.

Now, when running Play's 'stage' or 'dist' tasks it looks like all Javascript files getting uglified, that is, also files from the Webjar libraries.
[info] Uglify2 file: /target/web/rjs/build/lib/angularjs/angular.js

I would have expected that sources from the external Webjar libraries are left untouched as there already is a minified version. 
One problem with that is that the uglify process takes way too long. 
How can I speed up the uglification process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to speed up the Javascript building steps:

- Install node.js and set `export SBT_OPTS="$SBT_OPTS -Dsbt.jse.engineType=Node"` before running the `activator`. Using node.js instead of the default Javascript engine gives a very significant speedup. More details can be found here: [Migration to play 2.3](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.4/Migration23), see section about **sbt-web**
- Customize the build steps, e.g.

  - disable minification by adding to build.sbt: `RjsKey.optimize := "none"`
  - limit uglification by adding to build.sbt: e.g. `includeFilter in uglify := GlobFilter("myjs/*.js"),`

You can find more details about the options on the github site of these plugins:

[sbt-uglify](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-uglify)

[sbt-rjs](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-rjs)

Answer (score 1):

Even though that the sbt-uglify documentation says that excludeFilter should exclude webjars and public folder, it doesn't.

Follow Martin's reponse customization part, except that he maid y typo, add an S to RjsKeys:

```
RjsKeys.optimize := "none"
```